# how to get value from <select> and use it

Tags: javascript, html

So i have two lists like this

```
<select id="list1"> 
<option value="1">one</option> 
<option value="2">two</option> 
<option value="3">three</option> 
<option value="4">four</option> 
<option value="5">five</option> 
</select> 

<select id="list2"> 
<option value="1">one</option> 
<option value="2">two</option> 
<option value="3">three</option> 
<option value="4">four</option> 
<option value="5">five</option> 
</select> 

if (answer < 7) { 
greeting = "hello"; 
} else { 
greeting = "Good bye"; 
}
```

Now what I want to happen is to add both selected values. I.e. 2+4. Then I want to take the answer from the addition (6) and use it in a if, else statement.

I'm new to coding so if you could help me that would be awesome. Or resources that can help would be awesome too. I learn majority from w3schools.com

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `document.getElementById` to get the element by ID, and use `parseInt` to convert its string value to an integer.

```js
document.getElementById('link').onclick = function() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('list1').value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('list2').value);

  var answer = a + b;
  
  document.getElementById('result').innerText = answer;
};
```

```html
<select id="list1"> 
  <option value="1">one</option> 
  <option value="2">two</option> 
  <option value="3">three</option> 
  <option value="4">four</option> 
  <option value="5">five</option> 
</select> 

<select id="list2"> 
  <option value="1">one</option> 
  <option value="2">two</option> 
  <option value="3">three</option> 
  <option value="4">four</option> 
  <option value="5">five</option> 
</select> 

<a href="#" id="link">Calculate</a>
<div id="result"></div>
```

You just need to add your condition and use your `greetings` according to your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to access `document.getElementById("list1").value`. so:

```
+document.getElementById("list1").value + +document.getElementById("list2").value
```

Where `+item` will cast to a number, since the `value` is a string.

Comment: Nice + trick, I'm sure it'll come in handy code golfing.

Answer (score -1):

With jQuery:

```
<script>
var val1 = parseInt($("#list1").val());
var val2 = parseInt($("#list2").val());

var answer = val1 + val2;
</script>
```

Why `parseInt`? It's to convert the value of the options, which is a String, to a Integer so you can add them together.

If you'd prefer to not use jQuery, the code will be longer:

```
<script>
var list1 = document.getElementById("list1");
var list2 = document.getElementById("list2");

var val1 = parseInt(list1.value);
var val2 = parseInt(list2.value);

var answer = val1 + val2;
</script>
```